# Php curl for downloading facebook video

Tags: php, facebook, curl, video, download

I'm trying to build a php script that downloads youtube & facebook videos to my server.

This is my code

```
$url = "video_url";

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

$fp = fopen ('../cache_temp/file.mp4', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

This code works fine with `youtube` videos .. but with `facebook` videos it's not working, it only writes a `0 byte` file on my disk.

This is a direct link to a facebook video

https://video-cai1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xpa1/v/t42.1790-2/1192561_641914572487241_56890_n.mp4?oh=c43e04a7ec841e98a840b251964b4a6c&oe=5560DA5C

Can anyone tell me how can I download this video using php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i used this function and it works fine

```
    function copyfile_chunked($infile, $outfile)
{
    $chunksize = 100 * (1024 * 1024); // 10 Megs

    /**
     * parse_url breaks a part a URL into it's parts, i.e. host, path,
     * query string, etc.
     */
    $parts    = parse_url($infile);
    $i_handle = fsockopen($parts['host'], 80, $errstr, $errcode, 5);
    $o_handle = fopen($outfile, 'wb');

    if ($i_handle == false || $o_handle == false) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!empty($parts['query'])) {
        $parts['path'] .= '?' . $parts['query'];
    }

    /**
     * Send the request to the server for the file
     */
    $request = "GET {$parts['path']} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request .= "Host: {$parts['host']}\r\n";
    $request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n";
    $request .= "Keep-Alive: 115\r\n";
    $request .= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($i_handle, $request);

    /**
     * Now read the headers from the remote server. We'll need
     * to get the content length.
     */
    $headers = array();
    while (!feof($i_handle)) {
        $line = fgets($i_handle);
        if ($line == "\r\n")
            break;
        $headers[] = $line;
    }

    /**
     * Look for the Content-Length header, and get the size
     * of the remote file.
     */
    $length = 0;
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Content-Length:') === 0) {
            $length = (int) str_replace('Content-Length: ', '', $header);
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start reading in the remote file, and writing it to the
     * local file one chunk at a time.
     */
    $cnt = 0;
    while (!feof($i_handle)) {
        $buf   = '';
        $buf   = fread($i_handle, $chunksize);
        $bytes = fwrite($o_handle, $buf);
        if ($bytes == false) {
            return false;
        }
        $cnt += $bytes;

        /**
         * We're done reading when we've reached the conent length
         */
        if ($cnt >= $length)
            break;
    }

    fclose($i_handle);
    fclose($o_handle);
    return $cnt;
}
```

Comment: Does this code still work? I tried to insert a direct link to the video from facebook, nothing downloaded.